# Pandas: Counter column for each group after aggregatio

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas and dataframes here!
Initial dataframe:

```
A 1238 100

A 1238 90

A 3784 200

A 3784 500

B 1222 274

B 1222 400

C 2747 800

C 1384 100
```

I need the output as: (col C is min of the grouped data by col A and B, col B is a sequence counter for the grouped data):

```
A 1 90

A 2 200

B 1 274

C 1 800

C 2 100
```

Help!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) if in output is more like `3` columns for index of minimal values of `C` per groups with seelcting by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(['A','B'], sort=False)['C'].idxmin()]
```

Or aggregate `min` if only 3 columns in output:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False, sort=False)['C'].min()
```

And then create counter column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1['B'] = df1.groupby('A').cumcount().add(1)
print (df1)
   A  B    C
1  A  1   90
2  A  2  200
4  B  1  274
6  C  1  800
7  C  2  100
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, this is really helpful. How can I add a column to get max of C using the first method?

Comment: @wizkid Change `df1 = df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False, sort=False)['C'].min()` to `df1 = df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False, sort=False)['C'].agg([('minC', 'min'), ('maxC', 'max')])`